# Remove Full Quotes in Mail via Regex (PHP)

Tags: php, regex, email

I am trying to remove quotes in E-Mails. I have saved other Mails of that conversations in my Database as parsed HTML (as it is sent to the Users) if a user answeres on that mail and cites the whole mail in one block, I want to remove the full-cite.

But there's one Problem. Every Mail-Client marks a quote in its own style. Google uses blockquote, apple cite, some webmails are using divs and well - theres also plaintext, where a citation is marked with ">"

What I now want to do is to remove a quote if it quotes the Full text of one of the previous answeres.

I am using PHP

Comment: Whatcha tried or googled so far?

Comment: I have tried to convert both texts to plain-text (removing html) and remove ">"s and than identify the starting and ending line number. But the html line-number != the line number in the text file. There could have been "<br>"s between or other html, that was removed.

The other problem is to identify the Fake-Headers (Mail was sent at ... from to...) that is prepended to the citation

Comment: Woaaaa.... Haven't thought to end... Of course the line-breaks in my Text \n and not <br> than I could trim the text and maybe have it... Well... Talking about a problem often helps solving it. Thanks, Mario!